# Memory resource usage goes way up while resizing(by dragging) a dialog window in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc, imagemagick

I have got a problem about the memory resource usage getting very high while resizing (by dragging) a dialog box.

I've made a view on the dialog and done show bmp image in view.
But when I was resizing (by dragging) the dialog so many times, the memory resource usage increased very high.  I don't know where to start from.
What should I be checking?

My code concept as following.

```
CTestView::OnDraw(CDC * pDC)
{
...
DodisplayImage();
...
}  


Void CTestView::DodisplayImage(void)
{ 
if (m_pImage == NULL) { return; } 
PixelPacket *pPixels; 
CPoint pt; 
CRect rectClient; 
CDC * pDC; 
pDC = GetDC(); 
GetClientRect(rectClient);
 if (pDC != NULL) {
 int nImageY;
 int nImageX; 
 CSize sizeScaled; // Clear the background pDC->FillSolidRect(rectClient,pDC->GetBkColor()); 
...
BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi;
 bmi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); bmi.biWidth = m_pImage->columns(); 
 bmi.biHeight = (-1)*m_pImage->rows(); bmi.biPlanes = 1; bmi.biBitCount = 32;
 ...
,,BitBlt (...);
 DeleteObject(hMemDC);
}
```

I've followed dodisplayimage() at the like following link

ftp://ftp.mpe.mpg.de/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-5.3.3/contrib/win32/MFC/NtMagick/NtMagickView.cpp

Comment: Show the code for `OnPaint()` and `OnSize()`. Maybe somewhere it is calling `new`, but it's not deleting. Or it is calling `CreateXXXX` without following up with `DeleteXXXX`

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani : got it I'll prepare the detail code as soon as possible.

Comment: Barmak Shemirani explained the resource leak to you. However, your question is about "Memory resource usage...", so you must be leaking some memory, too. There is a pointer `PixelPacket *pPixels` in your code; how is it allocated? And is it freed?

Comment: @VladFeinstein Actually I have solved this problem by update VS2010 SP1 without Bamak's answer. Idon't know the reason, But It works.

Comment: I am reserving my rights to be skeptical :) Paraphrasing one respectable member here: if you don't know how you fixed the problem, you didn't.

Comment: You should use `CClientDC` the way I showed, that's the standard. The example from ftp://ftp.mpe.mpg.de link which you posted is wrong, it causes resource leak.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani yep, I got it, I've already applied your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a leak here:

```
Void CTestView::DodisplayImage()
{
    CDC *pDC = GetDC();
    pDC->FillSolidRect(rect, pDC->GetBkColor());
    ReleaseDC(pDC); //<= needs cleanup
}
```

`ReleaseDC` must be called to clean up after `GetDC`. See also documentation for [`GetDC()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71eseab0.aspx)

Or you can just avoid all that because MFC has classes with automatic cleanup. Replace `GetDC` with `CClientDC` every where in the code:

```
Void CTestView::DodisplayImage()
{
    CClientDC dc(this)
    dc.FillSolidRect(rect, dc.GetBkColor());
    //do stuff with HDC hdc = dc.GetSafeHdc(); ...
    //or CDC *pDC = &dc;
}
```

Comment: There are only 3 functions `DodisplayImage`, `OnPaint` and `OnSize` just edit your question and copy/paste. You can also monitor your program in Windows "Task Manager" [See Link](http://www.javelin-tech.com/blog/2011/01/low_system_resources_warning/) If there is something wrong, "Task Manager" will show GDI usage keeps going up specially when you resize.

Comment: I can't download your project and spend hours/days figuring out what it does and so on. You have to ask specific questions. If I have answered your question then you can accept it, or not.